# indexingerror: too many indexers on y dataset with 3 values for classification problem

Tags: indexing, scikit-learn, smote

I'm attempting to use SMOTE on my training data using sklearn. I have X data for the variables I'm using and the y data I want to predict. I created a function that works for y data with only two values (0, 1). However, I want to apply SMOTE for y data with three values (10, 30, 50) and I'm encountering the following error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[42], line 1
----> 1 mean_accuracy_ssmote = mean(cross_validation(classifier, X_train_F, y_train_F, oversampling = False)) *100

Cell In[41], line 15, in cross_validation(classifier, X_F, y_F, oversampling)
     13 for idx_F, (idx_train_F, idx_val_F) in enumerate (kfold_F.split(X_F)):
     14     X_split_train_F = X_F.iloc[idx_train_F, :]
---> 15     y_split_train_F = y_F.iloc[idx_train_F, :]
     17     if oversampling:
     18         sm = SMOTE(random_state = 42)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1067, in _LocationIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
   1065     if self._is_scalar_access(key):
   1066         return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
-> 1067     return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1068 else:
   1069     # we by definition only have the 0th axis
   1070     axis = self.axis or 0

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:1250, in _LocIndexer._getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1247     return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
   1249 # no multi-index, so validate all of the indexers
-> 1250 tup = self._validate_tuple_indexer(tup)
   1252 # ugly hack for GH #836
   1253 if self._multi_take_opportunity(tup):

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:869, in _LocationIndexer._validate_tuple_indexer(self, key)
    864 @final
    865 def _validate_tuple_indexer(self, key: tuple) -> tuple:
    866     """
    867     Check the key for valid keys across my indexer.
    868     """
--> 869     key = self._validate_key_length(key)
    870     key = self._expand_ellipsis(key)
    871     for i, k in enumerate(key):

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:908, in _LocationIndexer._validate_key_length(self, key)
    906             raise IndexingError(_one_ellipsis_message)
    907         return self._validate_key_length(key)
--> 908     raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
    909 return key

IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Here's my code:

```py
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

def cross_validation (classifier, X_F, y_F, oversampling = False):
  
    kfold_F = KFold(n_splits = 10)

    accuracy_split_F = []
    
    for idx_F, (idx_train_F, idx_val_F) in enumerate (kfold_F.split(X_F)):
        X_split_train_F = X_F.iloc[idx_train_F, :]
        y_split_train_F = y_F.iloc[idx_train_F, :]
        
        if oversampling:
            sm = SMOTE(random_state = 42)
            X_split_train_F, y_split_train_F = sm.fit_resample(X_split_train_F, y_split_train_F)
            
        classifier.fit(X_split_train_F, y_split_train_F.values.flatten())
        
        X_split_val_F = X_F.iloc[idx_val_F, :]
        y_split_val_F = y_F.iloc[idx_val_F, :]

        
        pred_split_val_F = classifier.predict(X_split_val_F)
        
        accuracy_split_F = accuracy_score(y_split_val_F, pred_split_val_F)
        
        accuracys_split_F.append(accuracy_split_F)
        
        print(f'Accuracy split {idx_F}: {accuracy_split_F}')
    
    return accuracys_split_F
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?